# re module in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have started to use  re module in python and write small program. got the following output.
I think it is correct replacement But I want modification in string Following way.
I tried but could not modify.Could anyone point out my mistake or idea

> str_result = //#define FULL_CHIP /* Turn on for chip level design */

```
import re
>>> str = "#define FULL_CHIP /* Turn on for chip level design */"
>>> str = re.sub(r'#define FULL_CHIP.*', r'\\/1',str)
>>> print str
\/1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex here:

```
>>> strs = "#define FULL_CHIP /* Turn on for chip level design */"
>>> if strs.startswith('#define FULL_CHIP'):
       strs = '//' + strs
>>> strs
'//#define FULL_CHIP /* Turn on for chip level design */'
```

If you still want to use a regex then use `()` to capture a group:

```
>>> strs = "#define FULL_CHIP /* Turn on for chip level design */"
>>> re.sub(r'(#define FULL_CHIP)',r'//\1', strs)
'//#define FULL_CHIP /* Turn on for chip level design */'
```

The above regex will replace all `#define FULL_CHIP` present anywhere in the string.

To replace `#define FULL_CHIP` that is at the start of the string use `^`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^(#define FULL_CHIP)',r'//\1', strs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem was more complex than stated and you did require RegEx's, the second line should be:

```
str= re.sub(r'#define FULL_CHIP.*',r'//\0',str)
```

The reason is that you want to produce `//` followed by the whole text matched.  That's group 0, not group 1.  Also, I don't understand why `/`s and `\`s appear inverted in `r'\\/1'`.  Let me know if any of my assumptions is wrong.